# How to test if Scala combinator parser matches a string

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I have a Scala combinator parser that handles comma-delimited lists of decimal numbers.

```
object NumberListParser extends RegexParsers {
  def number: Parser[Double] = """\d+(\.\d*)?""".r ^^ (_.toDouble)

  def numbers: Parser[List[Double]] = rep1sep(number, ",")

  def itMatches(s: String): Boolean = parseAll(numbers, s) match {
    case _: Success[_] => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

The `itMatches` function returns `true` when given a string that matches the pattern. For example:

```
NumberListParser.itMatches("12.4,3.141") // returns true
NumberListParser.itMatches("bogus") // returns false
```

Is there a more terse way to do this? I couldn't find one in the documentation, but my function sees a bit verbose, so I wonder if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: This is precisely what [`successful`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers$ParseResult.html) is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I should add my comment as an answer, since it is the answer. You can use the `successful` method on [`ParseResult`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers%24ParseResult.html), which is designed for precisely this purpose:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object NumberListParser extends RegexParsers {
  def number = """\d+(\.\d*)?""".r ^^ (_.toDouble)
  def numbers = rep1sep(number, ",")

  def itMatches(s: String): Boolean = parseAll(numbers, s).successful
}
```

This gives exactly the same behavior as your implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [JavaTokenParsers](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers) and benefit from `decimalNumbers`

```
object NumberListParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def number: Parser[Double] = decimalNumbers ^^ (_.toDouble)
  def numbers: Parser[List[Double]] = rep1sep(number, ",")
  def itMatches(s: String): Boolean = parseAll(numbers, s) match {
    case _: Success[_] => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `itMatches` as so:

```
def itMatches(s: String): Boolean = parseAll(numbers, s).map{ r => true }.getOrElse(false)
```

You don't need parser. `Regex` is enough:

```
var R = """\d+(\.\d*)?(,\d+(\.\d*)?)*""".r
def itMatches(s: String) = s match {
  case R(_*) => true
  case _ => false
}

scala> itMatches("12.4,3.141")
res0: Boolean = true

scala> itMatches("bogus")
res1: Boolean = false
```